# How to skip a word using re

Tags: python, regex

I´m trying to extract some 'words' from a text file
Part of the file text is:

```
Predicted XXX Area (NM): 88,0644
A    37 2.61 N,  1 12.75 W


XXX Track Vertices: 
 37 3.99 N,  1 13.02 W
```

Lines of interest

```
\tA\t37 2.61 N,  1 12.75 W
\t37 3.99 N,  1 13.02 W
```

I apply the following pattern

```
pat = re.compile(r'\s\s[1-9]?[0-9]\s[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}\s[NS],.+')
matcher = re.search(pat,text)
```

sol:

```
37 2.61 N,  1 12.75 W
```

How can I use regex to skip the the first line and catch the second one as follows ?

```
37 3.99N, 1 13.02W
```

Thanks

Comment: use [`^`](http://regex101.com/r/pJ7iD8/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for lines that begin with whitespace and digits:

```
pat = re.compile(r'^\s+[1-9]?[0-9]\s[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}\s[NS],.+')
                   ^^^^
```

The `^` matches beginning of line.  The `\s+` is for one or more whitespace.

You can't always trust consistency of whitespace, especially:

1. In this case when you specified `\t` in your lines of interest
2. In some cases when the source data is generated, shorter numbers could be padded with whitespace, and longer numbers would reduce whitespace to keep output looking even.

Answer (score 1):

Going off the data you provided: You can use the beginning of string `^` anchor in multiline mode.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''Predicted XXX Area (NM): 88,0644
    A   37 2.61 N,  1 12.75 W


XXX Track Vertices: 
    37 3.99 N,  1 13.02 W'''
>>> p = re.compile(r'^\s+([1-9]?[0-9]\s[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}\s[NS],.+)', re.M)
>>> re.search(p, s).group(1)
'37 3.99 N,  1 13.02 W'
```

Comment: thaks. I tried in the full file your soluction                       >> pat = re.compile('(?m)^\t\s[1-9]?[0-9]\s[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}\s[NS],.+') and returns '\t 37 3.99 N,  1 13.02 W'. Could you please explain the meaning of (?m)  and how can I avoid in the group the char \t and let just the numbers ?